# Google maps v2 end date

Tags: google-maps

We use Google maps v2 in our product and it was deprecated in May, 2010. I want to know whether Google will cease its availability sometime soon.

Can I still get the API key for v2?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use a deprecated version up to 3 years after the deprecation anouncement: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_4_4

> To create your API key, visit the APIs Console at
>   https://code.google.com/apis/console and log in with your Google
>   Account.
>
> Click the Services link from the left-hand menu, then activate the
>   Google Maps API v2 service.

Comment: However, I strongly recommend you move off of V2 and on to V3 right away. Baking in a V2 implementation means your map just won't be around that long.

Comment: Google will announce if we intend to discontinue or make backwards incompatible changes to this API or Service. We will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate the Service or the applicable APIs without these changes until the later of: (i) one year after the announcement or (ii) April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable good faith judgment):